# How to make React component's props typings depend on one another and get automatically inferred

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an abstract React component *(BaseTable)* that fetches an api and shows the result as rows in the table:

```
interface BaseTableProps {
  columns: Column<R>[];
  fetchData: () => Promise<AjaxError | R>
}

const BaseTable: FC<BaseTableProps> = ({
  columns,
  fetchData,
}) => { return .... }
```

Then I implement this base table with specific tables of data I want to show.

e.g if I want to show a list of todos I do it like this:

```
// the JSON type that is being returned from the API
interface TodoJSON {
  firstColumn: string;
  secondColumn: string;
}

const fetchTodosAPI: Promise<AjaxError | TodoJSON> = fetchAxios('/todos');

const columns: Column<TodoJSON>[] = [{ key: 'firstColumn' }, { key: 'secondColumn' }];

const TodosTable = () => {
  return (
    <BaseTable fetchData=(fetchTodosAPI) columns={columns} />
  );
};
```

The question is how do I type the typescript of BaseTable so that I can have the R generic equal to the data I am loading from API, in this case - TodoJSON.

If I could achieve this, I'd have the columns in BaseTable of Column type.

This way all fetchData and columns are related and I have safe types that are controlled from the implementation side.

If I was to change fetchData JSON response type in the Todo table, columns would automatically be inferred as the new JSON type.

Comment: Please share reproducable example. Try to copy/paste your code in TS playground and fix all errors. It will be much easier to help you